# How can I specify query parameters by routerLink directive

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-directives, angular2-router, angular2-router3

I am experimenting the new router (version 3.0.0-alpha.7) and would like to know how to specify query parameters by routerLink directive?

The Router.navigate() method below generates a URL like http://localhost:3000/component-a?x=1

```
this.router.navigate(['/component-a'], {queryParams: {x: 1}});
```

However, I can't figure out how to do the same thing with the routerLink directive. Template like below returns parser error...

```
<a [routerLink]="['/component-a'], {queryParams: {x: 1}}">Component A</a>
```

And the closest thing I can get is http://localhost:3000/component-a;x=1, which uses the syntax for child route.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/component-a', {x:1}]">Component A</a>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
<a [routerLink]="['/component-a']" [queryParams]="{x: 1}">Component A</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

In the new router component, you can do it in this way:

Passing a parameter in the URL:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/component-a', 1]">Component A</a>
```

Passing e query parameter:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/component-a', { x: 1 }]">Crisis Center</a>
```

Comment: Where is this documented?  I don't see this in the [master branch](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/@angular/router/src/directives/router_link.ts).

Comment: @Bernardo Pacheco how do you do this and pass it a variable for `x : 1`? Could you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/46574652/1440240