# Dynamic queryParams with a routerLink link in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-router, routerlink, query-string

I'm trying to pass a parameter to my routerLink within a loop. Here is what the array of objects looks like:
[image]

Here is the loop with the routerLink link:

```
<li *ngFor="let Achievement of AllAchievements">

    example from multiple sources
    does not work with a variable 'x'. Outputs the letter x
    <a routerLink="page" [queryParams]="{x : 1}">anchor text</a> 

    example from multiple sources
    link is outputted /%5B'page',%20%7BAchievement.type%20:%20'hello'%7D%20%5D'
    <a routerLink="['page', {Achievement.type : 'hello'} ]">anchor text</a>

    outputs long/encoded string as param value 
    <a [routerLink]="['page']" queryParams="{ [Achievement.type] : 'hello' }">anchor text</a>
</li>
```

Desired output: `<a href="page?position=hello"></a>`

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you are asking... how do you want the behavior to differ from the code you provided?

Comment: @KevinAud my apologies. I've updated the question with desired output = a traditional link with query parameters.

Comment: It would seem that you cannot make the key of the `[queryParams]` a dynamic value, but the value itself can be dynamic. You may have to rethink your approach.

Comment: Wow, I think you're right @R. Richards. Can't find anything online. Docs say `queryParams: {[k: string]: any}` not finding anything about it not capable of being dynamic.

Comment: I tried to get it to work, but I ended up getting run time errors. Maybe you could create a `payload` key, and pass some values from the json in the value, perhaps with a good delimiter.

Answer (score 3):

Old question but I just encountered this and since there's no answers this is the solution I came up with. Simple middle-man function to process the key

```
getRouterParams (key: string, value: string) {
  return { [key]: value };
}
```

then your HTML would look like

```
<a [routerLink]="['page']" [queryParams]="getRouterParams(Achievement.type, 'hello')">anchor text</a>
```

Works with interpolated strings also, which was the case I need it for

```
<a [routerLink]="['page']" [queryParams]="getRouterParams('achievement__' + Achievement.type, 'hello')">anchor text</a>
```